# How do I suppress the md5sum FAILED --check warning but still get the output?

Tags: linux, bash, md5, checksum, linux-mint

If I have a file named file1. And I then make an md5 file for file1, I then change the contents of file1, so the md5 is different. When I run a checksum on it, I will get

> /home/student/.trashCan/file1: FAILED.

This is what I want, however i also get

> md5sum: WARNING: 1 computed checksum did NOT match

How would i suppress this warning? So that i can get output from:

> /home/student/.trashCan/file1: FAILED
>
> /home/student/.trashCan/file2: OK
>
> md5sum: WARNING: 1 computed checksum did NOT match
>
> $student@osboxes

To this:

> /home/student/.trashCan/file1: FAILED
>
> /home/student/.trashCan/file2: OK
>
> $student@osboxes

If i use the --status flag, it will supress the warning but also the output. And if i use grep/awk/cut then i get my output, but i also get the warning.

Comment: Can you post what exact commands you're running?

Comment: @mjuarez md5sum --check .MonitorMD5CheckSum.md5 - I have tried piping this into awk/cut/grep etc. but the warning is always there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the output from `md5sum` is two parts:

```
$ md5sum --check test.txt.md5 
test.txt: FAILED
md5sum: WARNING: 1 computed checksum did NOT match
```

The first `test.txt: FAILED` line is sent to standard output.  However, the second line, that starts with `md5sum` is sent to standard *error*.  So, you can fix this by issuing your command this way:

```
$ md5sum --check test.txt.md5 2>/dev/null
test.txt: FAILED
```

This works because you're specifically telling it to send `stderr` to `/dev/null`.   `stdout` will still be displayed correctly.

Comment: You are an absolute star!! <3 I've been frying my brain out trying different methods of the --status flag and if statements. I knew about /dev/null but I had no idea that there are different classifications of messages you can send to the terminal. Thanks so much!!~